# Javascript/JQuery event arguments. I don't understand what this 'e' argument is or does

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery:

```
this.saveButton.click(function (e) {
    scope.saveForm();
});
```

This is a very simple line of JQuery that binds the .click() event to the saveButton object and calls a saveForm function when the event is fired.

When this event is called, what is 'e'?  I don't think it is ever used.

Comment: e is  Euler's number,  approximately equal to 2.7182818284 -- it's heavily used in logarithms and calculus. Your computer doesn't know this constant, which is why it is *absolutely essential* that you include it in all your event handlers, or risk exploding the entire Internet.

Comment: Looking back on my ignorance years later. Priceless :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `e` can be used to obtain specific information about the click (left, right or center; coordinates clicked; DOM object clicked on), but this specific code sample doesn't use it.

See http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ for details about what's available.

Comment: But who passes the 'e' argument?  The browser?

Comment: From the link: `The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler.`

Comment: Any event handler automatically creates it and passes it. I suppose that the OS is technically the creator of it. It's part of the magic.

Comment: @mblase75: jQuery creates it, and it's not magic at all. The original event is fired by the browser's DOM, jQuery catches and standardizes it and then calls your event handler functions.

Answer (score 2):

It's the event object. Take a look at the documentation page here:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers can take an optional parameter that contains information about the event that occurred. In this case, it is unused.

Answer (score 0):

`e` (or any other name you use) is an `Event` object. It is very useful when you, for example want to determine where did the `click` event take place or which key was pressed on `keydown` event.

You should read [this article](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) on jQuery API.

Example usage:

```
$("#someInput").keydown(function (e) {
  alert(e.which) // alerts the keycode of the pressed key
});
```